# A question about Weil restriction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, group-schemes

Let $\pi:\tilde{C}\rightarrow C$ be a ramified cover between two smooth curves. And consider a group scheme $\mathcal G$ over $\tilde{C}$, I have found two definitions for Weil restriction:

1. $Res_{\tilde{C}/C} \mathcal G$ is the group scheme whose sheaf of section is $\pi_*\mathcal G$.
2. The usual definition given in the book *Néron Models* by Bosch, Luetkebohmert and Raynaud.

My questions:

- Are these two definitions equivalent? (I didn't understand exactly the first one!)
- How could one calculate explicitly the Weil restriction for the constant group scheme $G\times\tilde{C}$, for a usual group scheme $G$.

Is there any good reference?
Thanks.

Comment: The definitions look the same to me.

Comment: In definition (1), $\pi_* \mathbb{G}$ is to be considered as a sheaf on the big Zariski (or etale, or ...) site of $C$, associating to a $C$-scheme $D$ the set ${\rm Hom}_{\tilde C}(D\times_C {\tilde C}, \mathcal{G})$, and then the definitions are equivalent. If we consider the small Zariski site of $C$, then of course the two definitions are not equivalent (often $\mathcal{G}$ will have no sections over Zariski opens).

Comment: Calculating the Weil restriction of a constant group scheme should be similar to calculating the pushforward of the structure sheaf $\pi_* \mathcal{O}_C$. You should get some complicated answer in terms of things like the ramification data of the cover. A simpler thing to understand is the generic fibre of this, which is just the Weil restriction of a constant group scheme with respect to a quadratic field extension.

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful answers, @Daniel Loughran I think your comment need to be expended to a good answer!! could you please do it? I am little bit confused and I don't see what you said...

Comment: Taking $G=GL_r(\mathcal O_\tilde{C})$ for example, is it true that $Res_{\tilde{C}/C}(G\times \tilde{C})=GL_r(\pi_*\mathcal O_\tilde{C})$ ?

Comment: @AllyMath: I don't really have an answer, only an idea how one would calculate it. Why do you want an explicit description so much anyway? Often in applications one only needs to know the cohomology, which one can easily calculate using the Leray spectral sequence.